# Extjs: Reuse the same grid in TabPanel

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

in a Extjs application I have a Grid and a Tabs line over it. Content of the Grid depends on the selected Tab. 
Say tabs has Jan-Feb-Mar-... values. Clicking of the Tab I would reload grid's store

Question: is it possible to avoid duplicating of the 12 grid components in favor to have one shared instance?

Thanks

Disclaimer: searching at the sencha's forum, google, stackoverflow was not successful :(

Answer (score 2):

It is, but it would require more effort than it is worth. Just create a prototype for your component, so that you can create new instances really quickly.

Comment: Yes, this is an obvious way, but I'm thinking about non-greedy application. I'm afraid I have to insert too many tabs/grids that caused unnecessary resources wasting.

Comment: If you use lazy instantiation (usng `Ext.reg()` to register your classes as new `xtype`s), your grids will only be actualy created, when the tab is selected, so this will help a little. You could also resign from having twelve tabs all together, and instead use one panel with a dropdown (or other widget) to select months.

Comment: This Q is still valid until now. I simply use `dockedItems` in ExtJs 4 with `boxready` and `resize` to make the height cover all body area. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I imagine that you could create a TabPanel with empty tabs and size the TabPanel so that only the tab strip is visible.  Under that (using the appropriate layout, border, vbox, etc.) create your GridPanel and use the TabPanel's `activate` event to reload the grid based on the currently-active tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following implementation meet your needs
1. Create your custom grid and register it 
2. place it tab panel

As the grid is created using xtype, it would not create 12 instances when you change tabs.

```
 Application.PersonnelGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
         border:false
        ,initComponent:function() {
            Ext.apply(this, {
                 store:new Ext.data.Store({...})
                ,columns:[{...}, {...}]
                ,plugins:[...]
                ,viewConfig:{forceFit:true}
                ,tbar:[...]
                ,bbar:[...]
            });

            Application.PersonnelGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        } // eo function initComponent

        ,onRender:function() {
            this.store.load();

            Application.PersonnelGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
        } // eo function onRender
    });

    Ext.reg('personnelgrid', Application.PersonnelGrid);

    var panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
                    items:[{  
                            title:'Jan', 
                            items: [{xtype:'personnelgrid'}]
                          }, { 
                            title: 'Feb', 
                            items: [{xtype:'personnelgrid'}]
                          }
                          ....
                           {
                             title: 'Dec',
                             items: [{xtype:'personnelgrid'}] 
                           }] 
                  })
```

Comment: shivashankar, thank you for the answer. On startup - you right, it will does not create no instances. It will create one later, the new clicked tab - the new gird's instance will be created. This is the same solution suggested by Mchl.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only place discussed about this until now, I share what I just found.

The **trick** is use `dockedItems` in **ExtJs 4** (Not sure either grid can be added into `tbar` in  ExtJs 3)
When changing the active tab, only body will be change but not the **docked item**. Just set the grid height equal to the body during `boxready` and `resize` so that we can't see the body anymore.

This is the code for ExtJs 4.2 MVC that also make use of `refs`.

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Notification', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['notification.List'],
stores: ['Notification'],
models: ['Notification'],

refs: [{
    ref: 'pnlNotif',
    selector: 'pnlNotif'
}, {
    ref: 'notifList',
    selector: 'notifList'
}],

init: function () {
    this.control({
        'dbPnlNotif': {
            added: this.pnlNotifAdded,
            boxready: this.calcNotifListSize,
            resize: this.calcNotifListSize,
            tabchange: this.pnlNotifTabChange
        }
    });
},

pnlNotifAdded: function (pnlNotif) {
    pnlNotif.add({ title: '1', html: '1' });
    pnlNotif.add({ title: '2', html: '2' });
    pnlNotif.add({ title: '3', html: '3' });
},

calcNotifListSize: function (pnlNotif) {
    // calc the notification list height to make sure it use the whole body
    // This way we can use only one instance of list to display for each tabs
    // because the list is rendered as dockedItems
    var height = pnlNotif.getHeight();
    var headerHeight = pnlNotif.getDockedItems()[0].getHeight();
    var tabBarHeight = pnlNotif.getDockedItems()[1].getHeight();
    height = height - headerHeight - tabBarHeight;
    if (this.getNotifList().getHeight() !== height) {
        this.getNotifList().setHeight(height - 1);// - 1 to include border bottom
    }
},

pnlNotifTabChange: function (pnlNotif, newTab) {
    // do something to filter the list based on selected tab.
}
});

Ext.define('ML.view.Notification', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: ['widget.pnlNotif'],
title: 'Notification',

dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'notifList'
}]
});

Ext.define('ML.view.notification.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.notifList',
dock: 'top',
store: 'Notification',

initComponent: function () {
    this.columns = [
        ...
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var gridJanName = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        enableColumnHide: false,
        autoScroll:true,
        store: storeJanNameGroup,
        border:true,
        stripeRows: true,
        columnLines:false,
        loadMask: true,
        tbar:tbgridTools,
        margin: '1 1 1 1',
        pageSize: 100,
        maxWidth:700,
        features: [groupFeature],
        selModel: {
            mode: 'MULTI'
        },
        columns: [
            {xtype:'rownumberer',width:50},
            {dataIndex:'id', hidden:true},
        //etc
        ]
    }); 
        var gridFebName = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        enableColumnHide: false,
        autoScroll:true,
        store: storeJanNameGroup,
        border:true,
        stripeRows: true,
        columnLines:false,
        loadMask: true,
        tbar:tbgridTools,
        margin: '1 1 1 1',
        pageSize: 100,
        maxWidth:700,
        features: [groupFeature],
        selModel: {
            mode: 'MULTI'
        },
        columns: [
            {xtype:'rownumberer',width:50},
            {dataIndex:'id', hidden:true},
        //etc
        ]
    });
    //
    //etc grid
    //


    var JanPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title:'Jan',
        bodyPadding: 5, 
        Width:780,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [gridJanName]
    });
    var FebPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title:'Feb',
        bodyPadding: 5, 
        Width:780,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        }
        //,items: [gridFebName]
    });
    var MarPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title:'Mar',
        bodyPadding: 5, 
        Width:780,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        }
        //,items: [gridMarName]
    });
    //etc
    var eachMonthstabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        minTabWidth: 130,
        tabWidth:150,
        //Width:750,
        scroll:false,
        autoHeight: true,
        id:'timestabs',
        enableTabScroll:true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype:JanPanel
            },
            {
                xtype:FebPanel
            },
            {
                xtype:MarPanel
            }
            ///etc
            ]
    });
```

Comment: Add some explanation for better understanding of users.

Answer (score 0):

For me good solution was to use a left toolbar called **lbar** with list of buttons and a single grid instead of tabpanel